# "...whose talents reaches..."

Tags: phrases

I think in the phrase "a professional climatologist whose talents reaches far beyond that field" should be "whose talents reach" or "whose talent reaches." Am I right? If so, what is the grammar rule in play here? Thanks!

Comment: "If so, what is the grammar rule in play here? Thanks!" I think it's called a typo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be prompted by a typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, due to subject verb agreement it should be either

> whose talents reach

or

> whose talent reaches

depending on whether it is a single talent or plural talents.